# How to use Net::DNS::RR:TSIG with key files generated by ddns-confgen?

Tags: perl, dns

I have been using `nsupdate` for a long time in various scripts dealing with dynamic DNS zone updates without any issue. I have always used TSIG to authenticate the requests against the DNS server, where the keys have been generated by `ddns-confgen`. That means that I didn't use key *pairs* like those generated by `dnssec-keygen`; rather, the keys file format is like the following:

```
key "ddns-key.my.domain.example" {
        algorithm hmac-sha512;
        secret "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij==";
};
```

The respective zone configuration then contains:

```
update-policy {
        grant ddns-key.my.domain.example name host.my.domain.example ANY;
};
```

Now I have a more complicated task and try to solve it by a `Perl` script. I have studied the documentation of `Perl::DNS::Update`, `Perl::DNS` and `Perl::DNS:RR:TSIG` and have studied a lot of examples which should make the usage of those modules clear.

However, each example I saw, when coming to signing a request via `TSIG`, used key files in the format `dnssec-keygen` produces, and not key files in the format I have. And indeed, something like

```
$o_Resolver = new Net::DNS::Resolver(nameservers => ['127.0.0.1']);
$o_Update = new Net::DNS::Update('my.domain.example', 'IN');

$o_Update -> push(update => rr_del('host A'));
$o_Update -> push(update => rr_add('host 1800 IN A 192.0.2.1'));
$o_Update -> sign_tsig('/etc/bind/ddns-key.my.domain.example.key');

$o_Reply = ($o_Resolver -> send($o_Update));
```

does not work, producing the following message:

```
TSIG: unable to sign packet at /path/to/script.pl line 240.
unknown type "ddns-key.my.domain.example" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Net/DNS/RR.pm line 669.
  file /etc/bind/ddns-key.my.domain.example.key line 1
  at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Net/DNS/RR/TSIG.pm line 403.

TSIG: unable to sign packet at /path/to/script.pl line 240.
```

I suppose I now have two options: Either use keys in the format `dnssec-keygen` produces, which seem to be directly usable with `Net::DNS` and its friends, or construct the TSIG key manually as shown in the docs:

```
my $key_name = 'tsig-key';
my $key      = 'awwLOtRfpGE+rRKF2+DEiw==';

my $tsig = new Net::DNS::RR("$key_name TSIG $key");
$tsig->fudge(60);

my $update = new Net::DNS::Update('example.com');
$update->push( update     => rr_add('foo.example.com A 10.1.2.3') );
$update->push( additional => $tsig );
```

[Of course, I wouldn't hard-code the key in my `Perl` script, but read it from the key file instead.]

Switching to another key file format would mean changing the DNS server configuration, which is not an elegant solution. "Manually" reading the key files and then "manually" constructing the keys is not very satisfying either, hence the question:

Did I understand correctly that it is not possible to use key files in the `ddns-confgen` format directly with `Net::DNS` and its sub-modules to `TSIG`-sign DNS update requests?

Comment: (unrelated comment: use `Class->new()` construct, and not `new Class()`, for reasons explained here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll look into the link you provided. Actually, I just have copied that example from `Net::DNS`'s documentation ...

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? I think the example in the Net::DNS::Update documentation is wrong. I have filled an issue at CPAN here:
https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132170

Comment: *did you manage to solve the problem?* Not really. I took the approach outlined at the end of my question (using improved code, but the idea is the same): I am explicitly reading the key from the key file and use it to construct the proper Tsig and Update objects.